# Headless Chrome in Selenium retrieves empty page (works without headless flag though)

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to get a page's contents using Chrome in headless mode but some pages return only empty HTML. My setup:

- Java 8
- Selenium Version 3.14.0
- Selenium Chrome Driver Version 3.141.59
- Testing on Windows 10

The code:

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setHeadless(true);
RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get("https://www.patagonia.com/home/");

System.out.println("Title: " + driver.getTitle()); // prints out "Title: "
```

When I do not use headless mode it works.

It also works if I use Firefox in headless mode.

Is there a setting I might be missing or why would that not work in headless mode?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: your example code doesn't even attempt to get page source.  please show the actual code.  also please remove all unrelated options you are setting

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg Since I don't know which options are unnecessary I posted them all. For Firefox I only need the headless option. Also my code retrieves the URL via driver.get(...). This is not a sample but actually working code (except for the problem I described).

Comment: I can confirm that this does **not** get the page source in **headless** Chrome for the given URL (running on macOS 10.13.6). All options (except `setHeadless(true)`) have **no** influence on the behavior (suggest to remove them from the question, @dsky). FWIW, taking a screenshot results a blank page. So obviously, the page does not load, when running Chrome headless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The webpage obviously detects when running Chrome Headless through the user agent (this is different when running headless, and will literally contain `HeadlessChrome`). Simple solution: Specify a Chrome non-headless user agent in your `ChromeOptions`, e.g.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
```

Here's how to specify it through the `ChromeOptions`:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
                            .addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36")
                            .setHeadless(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same problem with .NET, and it was because I was using a local insecure certificate in IIS.

To get around this, I added the following...

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
ChromeOptions.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
```

Pretty much, it tells the ChromeDriver options not to halt browser execution when an insecure certificate is detected, and to proceed as normal.

I also found it helpful when running into problems to run Chrome with the headless option turned off, to see what the browser is actually doing.