# Scraping website using headless = True returns about:blank as url

Tags: python, selenium, headless-browser

I am scraping a website and the code is working is fine in `headless = False` mode. Basically my code is scrapping the website, looking for certain links, and clicking on them. After clicking, a new tab is opening, so the webdriver is switching to new tab, fetching the link of the new tab and storing those links. This works fine as long as `headless = False`. When `headless = True`, the `url` value returned by code is returning is `about:blank`.

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--disable-notifications') #Disable notification send by chrome. Ex: ALlow location access.
    
    if headless:
        options.add_argument('--headless') #Run the automation in background
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_driver, options=options)
    driver.get(website_url)
    driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)

    for pos, link in enumerate(tqdm(links)):
        
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(link).perform() #To move the scroll bar to current element
        link.click()
        file_names.append(link.text)
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) #Switch to new window
        url = driver.current_url
        file_links.append(url)
        driver.close() #Close the new window
        
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0]) #Switch back to old window
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: What are the `links` here?

Comment: Some people suggest setting a user agent to avoid getting detected as a headless browser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54186955/headless-chrome-in-selenium-retrieves-empty-page-works-without-headless-flag-th

Comment: @Prophet, I am scraping this [this](https://www.ossiam.com/FR/documents) website. Links are each option shown on this webpage to download.